# function $f$ is analytic in the disk $\Delta= D(0,1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

a function $f$ is analytic in the disk $\Delta= D(0,1)$ and $|f'(z)|\leq c(1-|z|)^{-n-1}$ throughout $\Delta,$ where $n\in \mathbb N$ and $c>0.$ 
Show that $f(z)\leq cn^{-1}(1-|z|)^{-n}$ for  $z \in \Delta$ under the condition $n \geq 1.$

I really don't know why  $f'$ is bounded implies that $f$ is bounded. Maybe I can use Cauchy's estimate to do it, but I can not identify the  way to attack this.

Thank you so much!